# Appcelerator Titanium ACS Order place by nearest the user

Tags: iphone, cloud, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to order at list by nearest place. This is working fine with this code:

```
    Cloud.Places.query({
page: 1,
per_page: 20,
where: {
    lnglat: { '$nearSphere': [latitudefast,longitudefast],  }
    },

order: {
    lnglat: { '$nearSphere': [latitudefast,longitudefast],  }
    },
```

latitudefast and longitudefast is representing the actual position on the user. It has be defined before the query.

But it is "upside down", which means that the nearest place is in the bottom of the list, and the one farthest away is at the top of the list! How come? How do I order in reverse? Am i ordering wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not specifying the order? $nearSphere by default returns results sorted by distance.

From MongoDB's documentation (which ACS uses as its data store) describing $near:

> The above query finds the closest points to (50,50) and returns them
>   sorted by distance (there is no need for an additional sort
>   parameter).

This applies to $nearSphere as well.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing